# How to use this multiple times

Tags: javascript

I want to display this in several elements on the page. And it displays only once. In other elements it is empty. Do you have any solution regarding this issue?

Need to display it in a loop? Can you construct such a loop? As I created and wanted to display by class, no id unfortunately did not work.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

function getNextSaturday() {
  var now = new Date();
  var nextSaturday = new Date();
  nextSaturday.setDate(now.getDate() + (6 - 1 - now.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
  nextSaturday.setHours(11, 0, 0, 0);
  return nextSaturday;
}

function convertToEST(date){
  estOffset = -5.0
  utc = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
  return new Date(utc + (3600000 * estOffset));
}

var deadline = getNextSaturday();
initializeClock('clockdiv', convertToEST(deadline));
```

```html
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please replace the word *"this"* with the actual thing you want to address in your question

Comment: Provide an example of what you are asking.